# Programmatically using Django's loaddata

Tags: django, loaddata

I'd like to call the equivalent of `manage.py loaddata` from a Django view.  I'd like to be able to specify where to load the data from and which application to load it into.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Each `django-admin.py` (`manage.py`) command, as seen in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#running-management-commands-from-your-code), you can call from your code with:

```
from django.core.management import call_command

call_command('loaddata', 'myapp')
```

Where first param is the command name, all other position params are the same as command line position params and all keyword params are options.

Comment: you can also add option "verbosity=0" for supression console output: call_command('loaddata', 'fixture_name.json', verbosity=0)

Comment: Docs here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/django-admin/#running-management-commands-from-your-code

Comment: Please notice that **it is not suitable to use `loaddata` command directly in a data migration**, because it internally loads the most up-to-date model definitions and uses them to deserialize historical data in a fixture. That's incorrect behavior. Solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39743581/2293304

Comment: Also notice that **you should use the `app_label` keyword argument** to specify where to load the fixture, e.g. `call_command('loaddata', 'initial_data.json', app_label='myapp')`. Otherwise, it will load fixtures with the same name _from all installed apps_.