# How can i write the initial data for django 1.8

Tags: python, django, django-migrations

I want to have initial data for tables like `Users and Options`.

For old django the fixtures was very easy way to do but now django says to do it in migration way which i don't fully understood.

Now i already have 10 migrations in my migrations folder. I am confused where do i keep my initial data migration file .

If i make it like `0011_initial_data` and put it in other migration then it will get lost in long list of migration and its not easy noticeable to new user to see what is that . and also if someone squash the migration then no one will know if there is some data in there.

I want to keep it separate in some folder called data migration . How can i do that

This is the example code from their site. But where do i place it so that it don't get mixed up

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from django.db import models, migrations

def combine_names(apps, schema_editor):
    # We can't import the Person model directly as it may be a newer
    # version than this migration expects. We use the historical version.
    Person = apps.get_model("yourappname", "Person")
    for person in Person.objects.all():
        person.name = "%s %s" % (person.first_name, person.last_name)
        person.save()

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('yourappname', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(combine_names),
    ]
```

Comment: Here is the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25981899/548165

Comment: @catavaran i  want to keep that migration separate from other migration . IN that questions they Just keep fixture in separate folder but migration still is with other files

Comment: @user3214546 That's not possible, Django does not support multiple migration folders for a single app.

Answer (score 5):

Like @knbk said, you can't take the migration out of it's location. However, if you want your migration in between your other migrations, but have the fixture data in a separate file, you can do this:

```
from django.core.management import call_command
from django.db import models, migrations


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    def load_data(apps, schema_editor):
        call_command("loaddata", "initial_data.json")

    dependencies = [
        ('other_app', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(load_data),
    ]
```

Django will look for the fixture file the same way it always has and your data gets loaded when you migrate your db.

Comment: suppose  after running this migration , i change the data in my fixture file , then what will happen . how will same migration run again

Comment: You can roll back to the migration before your data migration, then simply call migrate and the migration will be re-applied, along with all later migrations.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-migrate