# Load fixture in django migrations using loaddata

Tags: django, django-migrations

My django application needs data to work properly, so in certain migration I loaded data using the recommended method by almost all stack overflow answers:

```
    from django.core.management import call_command

    def load_fixture(apps, schema_editor):
        call_command('loaddata', 'fixture_name', app_label='my_app')

    class Migration(migrations.Migration):

        ...

        operations = [
            migrations.RunPython(load_fixture),
        ]
```

In the following migration, I deleted a field and added another field. So far so good.

Now I want to test my application, but when the test database is being created, the 'call_command' above fails because the fixtures don't specify  values for the field created in the next migration. I suspect this is because `call_command` isn't loading the objects on the test database but on `settings.DATABASES['default']`.

How should I load fixtures in a migration so that I can build test databases?

Answer (score 0):

For tests, I know you can load in fixtures within Djangos TestCase, see [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.TransactionTestCase.fixtures)

For production, The approach you are taking using `loaddata` seems viable, but you would need to make sure your fixtures are kept up to date (as youve highlighted), as fixture inserting is quite forceful, an alternative is to create your models using the ORM inside of a `RunPython` operation, this can help to give them more flexibility..

There is a [feature request](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/24778) in Django for something more `official`, though I'm not sure if its being considered or not, but it would only add convenience for fixture loading, not a way to make fixtures dynamic..

[this other stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25960850/loading-initial-data-with-django-1-7-and-data-migrations/25981899#25981899) contains some other interesting approaches

Hope that's in some way helpful