# Populating value in a newly added field to models from a different table

Tags: python, django, django-models

Its Django 1.7, I have User model with `date_joined` field. I have another related model `Userprofile`. Also, the database is already existing with few thousand entries already.

Now, i want to add this `date_joined` field to `userprofile`

```
date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
```

And for the already existing rows in the Userprofile model, i want to put the value already there in the User model.

Although i can write a simple function to do this, I was curious if there is a simpler way to do that through models directly during creating that column only.

Comment: Yes, write an sql query. It's just a one liner.

Comment: It could also be done using [data migration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25960850/loading-initial-data-with-django-1-7-and-data-migrations)

Answer (score 0):

As you already know, `date_joined` is already present in your data - Django provides it by default. It sounds like you want to *duplicate* that existing data into your UserProfile instances. Duplicating data is never a good idea. It can go out of sync, you need to pepper your code with synchronization functions, etc. My advice is to NOT try to do what you're trying to do. Just utilize the existing data as needed. Django is giving you a "gimme" here and it sounds like you want to make things more complicated than they need to be. Remove `date_joined` from `UserProfile`.