# Django 1.10 - how to load initial users

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-migrations

What is the right way to load initial users in Django 1.10?

When we talk about our own django app then it is recommended to have a /fixtures/initial_data.json (as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25960850/loading-initial-data-with-django-1-7-and-data-migrations)).

But in the case of User, where  django.contrib.auth is not our app, where should we put the fixtures directory and how do we load it?

Thank you,

Rami

Comment: I didn't quite understand what you want. Do you want to insert data to your dB?

Comment: Yes. Only once, probably as part of a
$ python manage.py migrate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create fixture from default user model by below command:

```
python manage.py dumpdata auth.user -o FIXTURE_ADDRESS
```

and load initial data by below command:

```
python manage.py loaddata FIXTURENAME
```

that `FIXTURENAME` is name of your fixture in one of `FIXTURE_DIRS`.
The `FIXTURE_DIRS` by default is **fixtures**.

Comment: Thanks, this is an excellent pointer.
Is there a way to load the data as part as a migration, so to make sure it happens, and only once?

Comment: take a look at this link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25960850/loading-initial-data-with-django-1-7-and-data-migrations