# In Django, can you run seed data without always generating a migration?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, fixtures, seeding

I'm using Django and Python 3.7.  I have created a YAML file with seed data for my db ...

```
./myapp/fixtures/seed_data.yaml
```

How do I run this without generating a new migration for it, as is specified here -- [Loading initial data with Django 1.7 and data migrations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25960850/loading-initial-data-with-django-1-7-and-data-migrations) ?  I think theoretically there may be times when I add data to the file and my need to re-run it so it would be a little cumbersome to generate a new migration every time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Migrations will only run once, as you already correctly noticed :)

However, you can always manually run a `./manage.py loaddata <fixture>`. Don't know if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: Ah yes that "loaddata" was what I was missing!  Thx

Comment: You're welcome. But you still might've a problem when you're loading the same data twice. Django doesn't have any "magic" to prevent this (of course).

Comment: Maybe its because I have "pk"s in my yaml file, but running this multiple times doens't seem to result in any errors so I think I might be good.